# Jquery .span refresh onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am I correct in thinking this should work?

I have this jquery:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $(".wpsc_buy_button").click(function(evt) {
         $(".counter").load("index.php")
         evt.preventDefault();
      })
    })
</script>
```

This .span:

```
<span class="counter">              
    <?php 
        $i = 0;
        while(wpsc_have_cart_items()): wpsc_the_cart_item();
    ?>
    <?php $i += wpsc_cart_item_quantity();  ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php print $i ?>
</span>
```

And this button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" name="Buy" class="wpsc_buy_button" id="product_16_submit_button"/>
```

Comment: Yes that will work - i would add a `;` at the end of the `load` line for completeness ... if it doesnt work what were you expecting it to do ?

Comment: I want the span.counter to refresh when clicking the submit button. Doesn't seem to work for me though.

Comment: your code will overwrite the contents of `counter` doesnt look as if your sending anything to the server .. have a look at `get()` or `post()`

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Is your `input` part of a `form` group that has some kind of action attached to `submit`?

Comment: I see one problem. I'm trying to load index.php. Which is not needed. What I'd like to do is just refresh the php in the span.

You can view the code here: http://tobyclothing.com/shop/clothing/wife-beater/

I should add I do not know js:)

Comment: @ManseUK Thanks for your suggestions but they are above my head:)

Comment: @m90 Yes, it is. You can see it in use here: http://tobyclothing.com/shop/clothing/wife-beater/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the code to work this way:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $(".wpsc_buy_button").click(function(evt) {
        $.get("index.php", function(){
            var current = parseInt($.trim($(".counter").text()));
            $(".counter").text(current+1);
        });
         evt.preventDefault();
      })
    })
</script>
```

**UPDATED**

You're doing it the hard way. Here is the way you should do it:
Locate the file http://tobyclothing.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-core/js/wp-e-commerce.js?ver=3.8.7.6.2.494864 and find these lines: (line 248 - 257)

```
            jQuery.post( 'index.php?ajax=true', form_values, function(returned_data) {
                eval(returned_data);
                jQuery('div.wpsc_loading_animation').css('visibility', 'hidden');

                if(jQuery('#fancy_notification') != null) {
                    jQuery('#loading_animation').css("display", 'none');
                //jQuery('#fancy_notificationimage').css("display", 'none');
                }
   // add your NEW_CODE here
            });
```

your NEW_CODE will be:

```
    var current = parseInt($.trim($(".counter").text()));
    $(".counter").text(current+1);
```

which will then result in:

```
        jQuery.post( 'index.php?ajax=true', form_values, function(returned_data) {
            eval(returned_data);
            jQuery('div.wpsc_loading_animation').css('visibility', 'hidden');

            if(jQuery('#fancy_notification') != null) {
                jQuery('#loading_animation').css("display", 'none');
            //jQuery('#fancy_notificationimage').css("display", 'none');
            }
var current = parseInt($.trim($(".counter").text()));
$(".counter").text(current+1);
        });
```

**UPDATE 2**

If the user enters any number of quatity

```
var qty = parseInt(jQuery("input[name='wpsc_quantity_update']").val());
            jQuery.post( 'index.php?ajax=true', form_values, function(returned_data) {
                eval(returned_data);
                jQuery('div.wpsc_loading_animation').css('visibility', 'hidden');

                if(jQuery('#fancy_notification') != null) {
                    jQuery('#loading_animation').css("display", 'none');
                //jQuery('#fancy_notificationimage').css("display", 'none');
                }
    var current = parseInt(jQuery.trim(jQuery(".counter").text()));
    jQuery(".counter").text(current+qty);
            });
```

Comment: following the URL you posted, I dig into the code and found the way how to do it. Please check the updated answer. Regards.

Comment: Thanks again, but still doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Comment: Can you replace `'$'` with `'jQuery'` and try please? - `var current = parseInt(jQuery.trim(jQuery(".counter").text())); jQuery(".counter").text(current+1);`

Comment: It works! But it adds 1 as I should have figured from your code. But what if someone adds a quantity other than 2? Please check my comment below. Perhaps that will help you with what I'd like to do.

Comment: I seem to be getting close. I added the following on line 256 of http://tobyclothing.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-core/js/wp-e-commerce.js

`$('.counter').ajaxSubmit({success: function(){ /* refresh div */ });`

but it seems to refresh the whole page, or at least blank it out for a second. But it DOES seem to be getting me close.

Comment: I get it. Check the updated answer - we can get that quantity from the input

Comment: You're welcome bro :) BTW, I edited the code a little bit. Now `variable qty` assignment occurs before `jQuery.post` because, it is the safest way :)

Comment: that actually seems to have broken it:)

`var current = parseInt(jQuery.trim(jQuery(".counter").text()));
    jQuery(".counter").text(current+qty);`

Comment: I saw that. You didn't add this line: `var qty = parseInt(jQuery("input[name='wpsc_quantity_update']").val());` Look at the code again please.

Comment: Didn't notice that. Updated, but it seems to refresh the whole page now:/

Comment: There is a syntax error: `jQuery(".counter").text(current+qty);
            }); });` I think you mistakenly removed a curly brace and bracket

Comment: looks like I might have but it still refreshes the whole page for me. I reverted back to the old code which works fine. Could you explain to me why assignment of `variable qty` before `jQuery.post` is safer?

Comment: The difference is that, if you assign it before `.post` it means that you get the value of quantity from the user input as soon as the button is clicked (before the ajax request is sent). `function(returned_data) {}` is a callback function which is executed after the result is returned from the ajax request. Therefore there is some milliseconds delay between the button click and ajax result and there is a 0.01% chance (I mean very rarely) for the user to change the input text within that delay.